# Multiple ModelView Matrices in Vertex Shader

Tags: opengl, matrix, opengl-es, glsl, shader

Is it possible to have multiple modelview matrices in a single (vertex?) shader? I've gotten the following to sort of work, but I don't know if what I'm trying to do is recommended, or if there is an alternative approach to achieve something similar?

```
// inputs
attribute vec4 position;

// textures
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate0;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate1;

// matrices
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix0;
uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix1;

// output
varying vec2 textureCoordinate0;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate1;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position * projectionMatrix;
    textureCoordinate0 = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate0 * modelviewMatrix0);
    textureCoordinate1 = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate1 * modelviewMatrix1);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is that you want to achieve?

Comment: Just FYI: Matrix multiplications in OpenGL are right-associative, i.e. the multiplications should be written `matrix * vector` otherwise you're multiplying with the transposed matrix which is normally not what you want. With matrices and vectors `a * b =/= b * a`!

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I want to be able to have multiple (2+) textures as input, each with a separate modelview matrix. The reason behind it being in a single vertex shader, is because my approach wont work with separate shaders/glBlendFuncs as the alphas turn black. Perhaps there's a better approach to this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @datenwolf ah, thanks for that, so much for the commutative property of multiplication :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelview transformation usually is applied to the vertex position only. Texture coordinates normally are not transformed by the modelview, because it doesn't make a lot of sense in most situations.

Of course there are valid reasons to transform texture coordinates by a matrix, and you can of course pass as many matrix uniforms the OpenGL version you have permits.